# Как в java получить ЦЕЛОЕ рандомное число от 5 до 10(включительно/исключительно)?

Tags: java, android, случайные-числа, числа, int

Мне нужно получить ЦЕЛОЕ рандомное число от 5 до 10(включительно/исключительно). Как это можно риализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/random.php

Рекомендую использовать эту готовую функцию:

```
private static int getRandomNumberInRange(int min, int max) {

if (min >= max) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("max must be greater than min");
}

Random r = new Random();
return r.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
}
```

Но можно и без функции

Включительно:

```
 final Random random = new Random();
 int rand_int = random.nextInt(5)+6;
```

Исключительно:

```
 final Random random = new Random();
 int rand_int = random.nextInt(4)+6;
```